# How to display Chinese in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, fonts, chinese-locale

Here, I have a plot work to do with pandas, like this :

```
most_active_posts.plot(x = 'title',y = 'active_span',kind = 'barh')
```

`most_active_posts` is an object of dataframe with index, I want a simple two-dimensional plot with two columns, one is `'title'` and the other is `'active_span'`.

`title` is type of string, which contains Chinese characters, while `active_span` is type of integer .

How can I display Chinese characters normally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My work-around is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
font = fm.FontProperties(fname='c:\\windows\\fonts\\simsun.ttc')  # speicify font
ax = most_active_posts.plot(x = 'title',y = 'active_span',kind = 'barh')
ax.set_xticklabels(most_active_posts['title'].str.decode('utf-8'), fontproperties=font)
plt.show()
```

Basically, you need to specify a valid font for Chinese characters.

Answer (score 6):

I find a python library designed for fixing Chinese display in pip. You can download it using the command in your terminal:

```
pip install pyplotz
```

And you can write the following code instead(full code):

```
from pyplotz.pyplotz import PyplotZ
pltz = PyplotZ()
pltz.enable_chinese()
most_active_posts.plot(x='title',y='active_span',kind='bar')
pltz.xticks(np.arange(len(df.cn)),df.cn,rotation=360)
pltz.legend()
pltz.show()
```

[The result is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PG49.jpg)

And it can help you handle matplotlib Chinese font for you! This is the github page:

https://github.com/201528015329004/pyplotz

And there are some handy examples:

https://github.com/201528015329004/pyplotz/blob/master/examples/quick_start.ipynb

Comment: this solution works for https://colab.research.google.com/  as well

Answer (score 2):

1. Enter the directory `Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data`, and edit the file `matplotlibrc`.
2. Locate `font.family` and `font.sans-serif` then uncomment both of them and inset `Microsoft YaHei` after `font.sans-serif`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the characters to be the labels on the plot right?

I just grabbed some random characters:

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
   0 title
0  0     뉵
1  1     뉑
2  2     늘
3  3     度

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

I don't think there is a way to set `y_ticklabels` from `df.plot()`, but you can set them from the returned `axes` object:

```
In [47]: ax = df.plot(kind='barh')

In [48]: ax.set_yticklabels(df['title'].str.decode('utf-8'))
Out[48]: 
[<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x1152abfd0>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x1152a3910>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x111c5e790>,
 <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x111c5ef10>]

In [49]: plt.draw()
```

Here's the figure:

[image]

I'm not actually able to save the file and have the characters show up. Not sure why at the moment, but this may get you started.

Comment: Hei,friend!  I tried as you suggested ,unforunately problem still there . My situation much more like this :  s1 = Series([u'\u3010\u676d\u5dde\u3011\u7f8e\u8d44\u901a\u4fe1\u516c\u53f8\u6025\u62db\u524d\u7aef\u5f00\u53d1\u5de5\u7a0b\u5e08',u'\u730e\u5934'])
s2 = Series([15,16])
data = {'title':s1,'rate':s2}
df = DataFrame(data)
ax = df.plot(kind = 'barh')
ax.set_yticklabels(df.title.str.decode('utf-8'))
plt.draw()

Answer (score 0):

if you use pandas, you can use `get_xticklabels` to get labels and then set them with `set_xticklabels`.

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as mfm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

font_path = "/System/Library/Fonts/STHeiti Light.ttc"
prop = mfm.FontProperties(fname=font_path)
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt"]
figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
tmp = df.boxplot(by='shop', column='buy', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(tmp.get_xticklabels(), fontproperties=prop)
plt.show()
```