# How to plot a figure with Chinese Characters in label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

When I draw a figure with Chinese Character label in Python 3, it doesn't work correctly:

[image: Screenshot]]

**My code:**

```
fig = pd.DataFrame({
    '债券收益率':bond,
    '债券型基金收益率':bondFunds,
    '被动指数型基金收益率':indexFunds,
    '总收益率':ret})
fig.plot()
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.title('债券收益率',
          fontproperties='SimHei',
          fontsize='xx-large')
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis('tight')
```

Comment: [This](https://pythonpath.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/chinese-in-matplotlib/) works, provided you have the `SimHei` font installed. Note how they pass the font properties to the legend function.

Comment: Yes,It works!Thanks a lot!@Kartik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Chinese in pandas plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307832/how-to-display-chinese-in-pandas-plot)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass the font properties to `legend` function using the `prop` kwag:

```
from matplotlib import font_manager

fontP = font_manager.FontProperties()
fontP.set_family('SimHei')
fontP.set_size(14)

fig = pd.DataFrame({
    '债券收益率':bond,
    '债券型基金收益率':bondFunds,
    '被动指数型基金收益率':indexFunds,
    '总收益率':ret})
fig.plot()

# Note the next lines
plt.legend(loc=0, prop=fontP)
plt.title('债券收益率', fontproperties=fontP)

plt.grid(True)
plt.axis('tight')
```

---

[Source](https://pythonpath.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/chinese-in-matplotlib/)

Comment: tested not working in Ubuntu 22.04 / python 3.x

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['SimHei'] # Or any other Chinese characters
```

Answer (score 5):

Extending on Raphael's answer, for those using macOS, the system Chinese fonts is Heiti. To check if you have it:

```
import matplotlib
print([f for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist if 'Heiti' in f.name])
```

Then, do the following:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = ['Heiti TC']
```

For more here a [link](https://hoishing.medium.com/using-chinese-characters-in-matplotlib-5c49dbb6a2f7).

Answer (score 2):

macbook pro m1 solved by:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = ['Heiti TC']
```