# Matplotlib - Chinese characters are not shown when saving figure as 'eps' files

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, chinese-locale

The problem is described as the title.

For example:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['SimHei']

plt.figure()
plt.title('哈哈')
plt.savefig('try.png')
plt.savefig('try.eps')
```

Then, the results:

#### try.png :

[image]

#### try.eps :

[image]

The saving method works fine with 'png', 'jpg', but it cannot render chinese characters in 'eps'. Besides, you can find the number's font in the eps plot also looks weird.

Comment: Have you looked at these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39630928/9987623 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/21307832/9987623?