# How to show Chinese characters in Matplotlib graphs?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to make a graph based on a data frame that has a column with Chinese characters. But the characters won't show on the graph, and I received this error.

```
C:\Users\march\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py:238: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 19996 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0.0, flags=flags
```

[this is the picture of the graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtTDk.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display Chinese in matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307832/how-to-display-chinese-in-pandas-plot)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot a figure with Chinese Characters in label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39630928/7758804)

Comment: [matplotlib show chinese characters site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=matplotlib+show+chinese+characters+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk03UadVxnfL_qFeILJbYTEjSVfAwuw:1626979529280&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-2ZiHq_fxAhVJsp4KHbvuCrwQrQIoBHoECAkQBQ&biw=1920&bih=975)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to ensure that you are using a font that has the glyphs you want to use. Take a look at [text with non-latin glyphs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_props.html#text-with-non-latin-glyphs)

From the above link:

> As of v2.0 the default font, DejaVu, contains glyphs for many western alphabets, but not other scripts, such as Chinese, Korean, or Japanese.
> To set the default font to be one that supports the code points you need, prepend the font name to 'font.family' or the desired alias lists

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Source Han Sans TW', 'sans-serif']
```