# How do I render multiple languages (e.g. Chinese, cyrillic, english) at once in a legend using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode, fonts, legend

I am plotting statistics related to different translations of a word. Using python / matplotlib under Ubuntu I cannot get my legend to show all my languages.

My code below

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('pgf') # This may make things harder; solutions without it are still of interest
# pip3 install matplotlib==3.5
plt.close('all')

fig,ax= plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(1,1,'.',label='english')
ax.plot(1,2,'.',label='Glück')
ax.plot(1,1,'.',label='доход')
ax.plot(1,1,'.',label='幸福')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('tmp.pdf')
plt.savefig('tmp.png')


print(matplotlib.__version__)
```

seems to do fine with various Unicode, but not Chinese. I get the following:

[image]

```
/home/meuser/tmpbug.py:23: UserWarning: Glyph 24184 (\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5E78}) missing from current font.
  
/home/meuser/tmpbug.py:23: UserWarning: Glyph 31119 (\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-798F}) missing from current font.
  
/home/meuser/tmpbug.py:23: UserWarning: Glyph 24184 (\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5E78}) missing from current font.
  
/home/meuser/tmpbug.py:23: UserWarning: Glyph 31119 (\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-798F}) missing from current font.
  
/home/meuser/tmpbug.py:24: UserWarning: Glyph 24184 (\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5E78}) missing from current font.
  print(plt.__version__)
/home/meuser/tmpbug.py:24: UserWarning: Glyph 31119 (\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-798F}) missing from current font.
  print(plt.__version__)
3.5.0
```

How can I get all my  labels to show in one legend?
If this is not possible, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Looking this problem up, I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307832/how-to-display-chinese-in-matplotlib-plot) that uses [pyplotz](https://github.com/songlinhou/pyplotz). I adapted it to your problem and it seems to be solving your issue:

```py
!pip install pyplotz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

from pyplotz.pyplotz import PyplotZ
pltz = PyplotZ()
pltz.enable_chinese()


fig,ax= plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(1,1,'.',label='english')
ax.plot(1,2,'.',label='Glück')
ax.plot(1,1,'.',label='доход')
ax.plot(1,1,'.',label='幸福')

pltz.legend()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

This was tested on google colab with matplotlib 3.2.2 and 3.5.0

**EDIT:**

Here is a way to create two legends one for the chinese characters and the second one for the other languages. Here is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import font_manager
from pyplotz.pyplotz import PyplotZ
pltz = PyplotZ()
pltz.enable_chinese()


fig,ax= plt.subplots(1)

e,=ax.plot(1,1,'.',label='english')
g,=ax.plot(1,2,'.',label='Glück')
r,=ax.plot(1,1,'.',label='доход')
c,=ax.plot(1,1,'.',label='幸福')
legend=plt.legend([e,g,r],['english','Glück','доход'],loc='best',bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0., 0.5, 0.5),frameon=False)
legend1=pltz.legend([c],['幸福'],loc='best',bbox_to_anchor=(0.452, -0.21, 0.5, 0.5),frameon=False)
plt.gca().add_artist(legend)
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The font is now rather ... ugly, especially the Russian, which seems not to be proportionally spaced. Is it possible to fix the Chinese without ruining the other languages/fonts?

Comment: You could always create two legends. One for the chinese characters and the other one for the rest. See edit of my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for this!     You can simplify the legend calls with `handles=[c]` rather than specifying handles and labels.    Your example works for me, but implementing it in my code still gives garbage for the pltz legend for some reason.  Also, I would need the 2nd legend to situate itself right under the first, regardless of the size of the first. (I am producing dozens of plots, all different).   I am still hoping for an answer that renders labels in one legend.  This is neato but not usable for me, as is.

Comment: It turns out my application also (weakly) requires `matplotlib.use('pgf')`, which I've added to the question.  For some reason this makes your code not render properly again.